# geting int back from string

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have my score which is an int sent to an sqlite database as a string using .toString() method

When I retrieve it back how do I turn it back to an int?

I have tried looking online, but have got mixed results

Comment: To avoid the next question, an empty string does NOT parse to zero.

Comment: That's a little condescending

Comment: I didn't mean it to be.  It's just one of the common questions on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
int returnValue = Integer.parseInt(returnValueFromSql);
```